# css inline style - style="background-image:url for local image

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, inline-styles

I would load the image Hormiga.jpg by inline style as back-ground for my slideshow but the attribute url is not correctly applied.

This is the original code from where an image is loaded correctly:

```
<div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image:url(./images/nature-1.jpg)" data-swiper- 
      parallax="-23%"></div>
```

The above code is not my code. I have the following paths:

- myapp/templates/myapp/index.html
- myapp/static/images/Hormiga.jpg

From the index.html the images are called correctly like below but for  css inline style is not working...:

```
"{% static 'images/Hormiga.jpg' %}"
```

The following ones are not working

```
style="background-image:url"({% static 'images/Hormiga.jpg' %})""
style="background-image:url("{% static 'images/Hormiga.jpg' %}")"
style="background-image:url"(../images/Hormiga.jpg)""
style="background-image:url(images/Hormiga.jpg)"
style="background-image:url(../myapp/static/images/Hormiga.jpg)"
```

Any help will be appreciated.
The root is static/images/Hormiga.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what this static line you are using is, and you have quotes where you dont need them

Use this if the image folder is in the same directory

```html
style="background-image:url('./images/Hormiga.jpg')"
```

or this if it is in the directory above.

```html
style="background-image:url('../images/Hormiga.jpg')"
```

Comment: This worked, style="background-image:url('../static/images/Hormiga.jpg')" thank you sir, appreciated. Asap I could assign votes I will remember to give you one :)

Comment: @VincenzoDelre Just remember to mark question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Hello I checked your question your code is fine,
but you have to define width and height as well for it to be visible

```html
<div class="parallax-bg" style="background-image:url(./images/nature-1.jpg); width: 100px; height: 100px;" data-swiper- 
      parallax="-23%"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is not my code. I have the following paths:myapp/templates/myapp/index.html and myapp/static/images/Hormiga.jpg

Comment: Hi, if you would be so kind to have a look on the question now... I have edit it few seconds ago. Thanks

Comment: sorry I am new to stackoverflow I thought these notifications were some ads